# Dereferencing NULL pointer warning when checking if char* is null or empty

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

So simply put, I am checking if two char* are either nullptr or empty through an `if` statement but I get a warning saying I am dereferencing a null pointer.

```
// mplate is a reference to a class
if ((mplate.m_plate != nullptr || mplate.m_plate[0] != '\0') || (plate != nullptr || plate[0] != '\0')) {
// Do something
}
else {
// do something else
}
```

So basically i'm trying to say in the `if` statement is if either `mplate.mplate` or `plate` is empty or `nullptr` do this otherwise do something else.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'make'.
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'model'.
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'mplate.m_plate'.
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'plate'.
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'plate'.
```

Comment: Can you copy the whole warning? Including error and so on.

Comment: Simply put, you want both conditions to be `true` before proceeding, thus the correct logical operation is `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: The expression `(mplate.m_plate != nullptr || mplate.m_plate[0] != '\0')`  - which is part of your test in the `if()` - will evaluate `mplat.m_plate[0]` ONLY if `mplate.m_plate` is null - therefore will give undefined behaviour.    You need `&&` instead of `||` in that expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing something like

```
if (p != nullptr || *p)
```

i.e. you are dereferencing *only if* the pointer is `nullptr`. This means you do nothing if the pointer is valid, or you dereference if it's invalid (which is UB).

You need to do a logical `and` instead, like this

```
if (p != nullptr && *p)
```

i.e. only dereference if the pointer is *not* `nullptr`.

Comment: In fact, `p != nullptr || *p` is ONLY dereferencing `*p` if `p` is `nullptr`.   So it either does nothing, or it causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your question states that you want to execute the `if` block if either pointer is NULL or points to `'\0'`, so you really want this:

```cpp
// mplate is a reference to a class
if (mplate.m_plate == nullptr || mplate.m_plate[0] == '\0' || plate == nullptr || plate[0] == '\0') {
// Do something (Block entered on the FIRST true test...)
}
else {
// do something else ( Block entered ONLY if all four tests are false...)
}
```

In this code, the tests in the `if` statement will 'short-circuit' as soon as any one of the tests is `true`, so you will never dereference a `nullptr`.